# Xilinx ISE - Maximum frequency

Tags: max, frequency, xilinx, spartan

I'm trying to synthetize any simple project in ISE for Spartan 6.
When I use Clocking Wizard for clk generator with f = 40 MHz (100Mhz external oscillator), XST says:

### Timing Summary:

Speed Grade: -3

Minimum period: 9.482ns (Maximum Frequency: 105.458MHz)
   Minimum input arrival time before clock: 2.623ns
   Maximum output required time after clock: 3.597ns
   Maximum combinational path delay: 5.194ns

OK, but when I change clk frequency in core generator to 100MHz, the response is Maximum Frequency is about 47MHz ...

What is wrong?
What is the right way to determine max frequency?

Comment: Some questions: Have you applied timing constraints in synthesis? Have you checked if CoreGen changes the period generics of the mmcm accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

The reported maximum frequency in synthesis is only a rough estimation based on fanout, LUT levels, i/o-buffers, ...

The real timing analysis is done after Place & Route.

I have a project which already utilizes synthesis timing constraints (additional xcf-file), were XST reports f_max = 82 MHz. After P&R the design achieves 152 MHz :)